# ASP disable button during postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a button which i am trying to add a css class to appear disabled once the user has clicked it.

```
protected void Button_Continue_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel_Error.Visible = false;
        Literal_Error.Text = "";
        if (RadioButton_Yes.Checked)
        {
            ...//if radio checked get text and process etc.
        }
    }
```

My button onlick is above which simply processes a textbox filled on the page.

My button looks like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button_Continue" CssClass="button dis small" Text="Continue" OnClick="Button_Continue_OnClick" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return preventMult();" />
```

And my javscript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isSubmitted = false;
function preventMult() {
    if (isSubmitted == false) {
        $('#Button_Continue').removeClass('ready');
        $('#Button_Continue').addClass('disabled');
        isSubmitted = true;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem I am having is that the css class added works fine on the first postback, but after which my button onclick doesnt work and the button cant be clicked again if the user needs to resubmit the data if it is wrong

Another problem I am having is that with a breakpoint in my method i notice that the method is fired twice on the click.

Comment: where in your code are you checking for `IsPostBack`

Comment: @DJKRAZE Im doing it in Page_Load()

Comment: can you show that code for your Page_Load(); perhaps you can do `__DoPostBack` JavaScript code for this event as well `Button_Continue_OnClick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need something like this:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
    //doNothing
    }
else
    {
    //button.disabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button_Continue" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="button dis small" Text="Continue" OnClick="Button_Continue_OnClick" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return preventMult();" />
```